# source path is nil--but plist is in bundle resources

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting a "source path is nil" error, but the plist that's supposed to be at the source path is in the bundle resources.

Code:

```
{NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gHaiku413.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gHaiku413" ofType:@"plist"];
            NSLog(@"%@",bundle);
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];

}
```

When I go to Build Phases and look in Copy Bundle Resources, gHaiku413.plist is definitely there, but the result I get is:

```
//This is the output of NSLog(@"%@",bundle):
2013-09-18 16:49:22.728 GHaiku[39389:a0b] (null)
2013-09-18 16:49:22.733 GHaiku[39389:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Clearly one thing you are missing is a guard to check if your path string is nil before passing it to the file manager method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is just a typo in your question, or the actual problem, but `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gHaiku413" ofType:@"plist"];` looks for `gHaiku413.plist` and you said that the file `gHaiku.plist` is definitely there. These are different file names.

**Update:** After discussion in comments it turned out to be this:

1. Try a very-clean build: <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and failing that, an uber-clean build:

   - Close Xcode
   - Delete both `xcuserdata` directories: `MyProject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata` and `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata`
   - Delete the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` directory
   - Restart Xcode
   - Build
2. Reset content and settings in the simulator

Comment: Alas, that was a typo--the file gHaiku413.plist is there. Fixed question. :(

Comment: Not sure then. Make sure it's in the correct target, then try an uber-clean build (cmd+opt+shift+K, close Xcode, delete both xcuserdata directories, delete DerivedData, restart Xcode, build). Also reset content and settings in the simulator.

Comment: Well, this took care of it. Thanks!